# Can't access mysql database after changing its directory

Tags: php, mysql, raspberry-pi

I am trying to connect to a mysql database and I keep getting this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi /var/lib/mysql $ sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

After moving my database files onto an external flash drive (`/media/my_flashdrive`), then moving everything back to `/var/lib/mysql`:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock #ORIGINAL
#socket          = /media/my_flashdrive/mysqldb/mysqld.sock #ADDED
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql #ORIGINAL
#datadir         = /media/my_flashdrive/mysqldb #ADDED
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1   ###CHANGED
```

The permissions on all files inside the mysql folder are root. Can someone explain what I did wrong here?

Comment: MySQL daemon runs without root privileges so it can't access database files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98467/how-to-solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-error

Comment: Thanks, despite multiple google searches for a solution to this problem I did not find the link you posted. The answer in the link fixed my issue.